# Setup future payment method PayPal in flutter_stripe

Tags: flutter, paypal, stripe-payments

I am trying to setup future payment method for PayPal and I am getting this error.

await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
paymentSheetParameters: const SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
setupIntentClientSecret:
"seti_1OuCs4LiqSZoNeCk9JuMfuvt_secret_PjgEOcH1iqZOvE7tU5f17kmtW9vRIsh",
style: ThemeMode.system,
allowsDelayedPaymentMethods: true,
merchantDisplayName: 'MyApp',
),
);

flutter: StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds, message: There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds, stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null))

Comment: This error is generally indicative of the intent (and secret) being created on a different Stripe to the one that initialised the Payment Sheet (via the API keys). Either that, or you've not correctly configured your merchant ID. Details [here](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/373#issuecomment-1129908664). I'd recommend speaking with the library maintainers directly as this is not an official Stripe SDK.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.